# Deferring DataGridView update when editing the underlying DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net, datagridview

If you have a DataGridView that is bound to a DataView (someDataTable.DefaultView).

..and a number of edits are performed on rows in the underlying DataTable from code.

Is it possible to defer the updating of the DataGridView until you decide that you are finished editing rows?

As it is, the DataGridView is updated after every edit, which, if you don't require instant feedback, is inefficient and a little visually jarring if you are updating many rows in the DataTable one after the other.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to be able to temporarily suspend data binding, you'll have to put a [`BindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.raiselistchangedevents.aspx) between your `DataGridView` and your `DataView`. By setting the `RaiseListChangedEvents` property of the `BindingSource` to false, changes in the underlying source are not notified to the `DataGridView`. You can drag & drop a `Bindingsource` component from the toolbox in the design view. I tried to set up the data sources via the designer but it didn't work, so I did it in code:

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = someDataTable.DefaultView;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

To suspend data binding, just set the `RaiseListChangedEvents` property to false:

```
bindingSource1.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
```

To resume data binding, just set the `RaiseListChangedEvents` to true and reset the bindings so the display is updated:

```
bindingSource1.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);
```